# SQL case when error

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello my sql query still returns else case but  I am pretty sure that inner select returns 1. What`s wrong with the code?

```
SELECT CASE a_from
WHEN (SELECT a_from REGEXP 'something.com>$' = 1 )
     THEN "S"
ELSE "T"
END AS 'HP', a_from FROM article WHERE id =4
```

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN a_from REGEXP 'something.com>$' = 1 THEN 'S' ELSE 'T' END AS hp, a_from FROM article WHERE id = 4 ;`

Comment: Than U so much. It is working. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed the `where` in your inner select statement.

```
SELECT CASE a_from
WHEN (SELECT a_from REGEXP where 'something.com>$' = 1 )  <-- Here 
     THEN "S"
ELSE "T"
END AS 'HP', a_from FROM article WHERE id =4
```

As commented by ypercube you may try like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a_from REGEXP 'something.com>$' = 1 
 THEN 'S' 
ELSE 'T' END AS hp, a_from 
FROM article WHERE id = 4 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be missing a WHERE in your inner select

```
(SELECT a_from REGEXP WHERE 'something.com>$' = 1 )
```